# Multiple environment configuration with android xml config on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, configuration-files

My android application could run on multiple environments - dev/test/live.
I have few config values that are different between the environments (and a lot of values that are the same for all of them).

Is there an easy way to keep a configuration xml file with few states in eclipse, that when changing between them, some of the keys and values will be changed?
(like DEBUG/RELEASE in .net)